# Changing colors of edit fields in attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table

Does anyone know of a way to change the background color of fields in the attribute table window whilst in edit mode?

I need this because I am manually editing hundreds of point attributes and it would be very helpful for efficiency to somehow mark which attributes are required and which ones are optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is supported in versions > 10.

1. Open up attribute table
2. Access field properties (right click header)

[image]

Comment: I was looking for something along these lines.... thank you

Answer (score 2):

While the previous answer is only temporary while the table is open. It is the only method for changing column colors.
Table settings are in the arcmap options dialog.
[image: Table settings]
These color settings affect selected rows.

Comment: This is essential if you're using a high contrast desktop coloring scheme.